# Script to open right-click menu and choose menu item

Tags: autohotkey

In a specific program, I want to assign a hotkey to the action of right clicking at the cursor's current position, then moving the cursor to choose an item on that menu, then moving the cursor again to choose an item on the sub-menu. I've gotten as far as the first two commands. When I get to the mousemove, no matter what coordinates I put in, the cursor shoots to the upper left corner of the screen, when what I would like it to do is first move 100 pixels to the right and 60 pixels up, then 100 pixels to the right, zero pixels on the y-axis. Clearly I am misunderstanding something. Please advise.

Thanks,
Ellen

```
   s::

MouseGetPos

Click right

sleep, 100

MouseMove, 60, -60, 5, R

Sleep, 100

MouseMove, 200, 0, 5, R

MouseClick, L

return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't `Mousemove` be `MouseMove` instead? It's like that in the [docs](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/MouseMove.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Ellen, first of all, if at all possible try if you could use keyboard shortcuts.
Please check: Control Panel\Ease of Access Center\Make the keyboard easier to use\Underline keyboard shortcuts and access keys. This will show the shortcuts that you can use. This way you might even find the keyboard shortcut for the menu, instead of using the mouse location.

```
^+b:: ; Record the location of the menu at the beginnin with [Shift]+[Ctrl]+b
SoundBeep, 500, 500
ToolTip, Click on the "XYZ" Link
KeyWait, LButton, D
MouseGetPos, xPos, yPos
Send, {Esc}
ToolTip
Return

^b::
MouseClick, Right, xPos, yPos
;Mousemove, 100, 60 R
Send, e : OR WHATEVER Shortcut letter OR.....
Send, {Down 3}{Enter} ; IF you want to use down arrow 3 times to get to the item.
Return
```

Modified, where YOU have to position the mouse on the always changing menu position.

```
^b::
    MouseClick, Right ; presses where the mouse is located
    ;Mousemove, 100, 60 R
    Send, e : OR WHATEVER Shortcut letter OR.....
    Send, {Down 3}{Enter} ; IF you want to use down arrow 3 times to get to the item.
    Return
```

If you can identify the menu ID (with AHK Windows Spy, place the mouse over the menu and look at "under the mouse"), you could use controlsend. This would be location independent since controlsend will use the menu ID to send a signal. If you tell me which application you try to control, I could see if controlSend could be used....

Oh b.t.w. I did not know you used XP, the enable shortcut instructions were for Windows 7.

Comment: Robert, I'm not following what you're suggesting. I don't understand what to do with that extra script that you wrote. I still consider it safe to call myself very much a beginner who only has occasional flashes of understanding. If it makes my question any clearer, this is for that program that has strange window names that keep changing, and the menus as far as I can tell have the same problem. Plus, this is not for a fixed point, but for any selected node on a vector contour, thus a moving target.

Comment: Enabled Show Extra Keyboard Help in accessibility options (XP), but don't see anything yet like what you're describing.

Comment: It doesn't work if the selected node is at the top of the window because the menu placement changes so I'd still like to do it a better way if I could.

Comment: Ellen, I had hoped that the menu would stay at the same place for each session, that is why I opted to record the menu position with the first script so that once the position is recorded, you could just press ^b to always go to the same (pre-recorded) position and run the script from there. If the menu position changes constantly, then the only way is to position the mouse first and then run the modified macro. Another way is to use the shortcuts or use a text/image search to locate the menu.

Comment: The trouble is, this particular program, TypeTool 3, has weird window titling and Window Spy doesn't show anything in particular for any menus. I'm just going to have to let this one go for the moment. My next macro attempt will involve a program that has normal window and menu titling. I'm going to investigate ControlSend and if I can I'll play around with that, too.

Answer (score 0):

- This AutoHotkey script, including a user-created AutoHotkey function should do what you require.
  It automates right-clicking a program, and then selecting 3 items on subsequent menus.
- The script has been written to work on Media Player Classic,
  but certain lines just need to be edited to make it work for your program, TypeTool 3. You specify a comma-separated list with one or more items, i.e. the name of the item to choose in the first menu, and in the second menu item etc.
- The vast majority of programs use standard context menus,
  so it should work on your program; this is in contrast
  to menu bars and other types of controls/resources that vary more between programs.

-

```
;note: requires Acc.ahk library in AutoHotkey\Lib folder
;https://github.com/Drugoy/Autohotkey-scripts-.ahk/blob/master/Libraries/Acc.ahk
;on right of screen right-click Raw, Save target as...

;the currently assigned hotkey is ctrl+q
;e.g. Media Player Classic, open right-click menu, click items
#IfWinActive, ahk_class MediaPlayerClassicW
^q::
WinGet, hWnd, ID, A
WinGetClass, vWinClass, ahk_id %hWnd%
if vWinClass not in MediaPlayerClassicW
Return
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
MouseGetPos, vPosX2, vPosY2

WinGetPos, vPosX, vPosY, vPosW, vPosH, ahk_id %hWnd%
vPosX := Round(vPosX + vPosW/2)
vPosY := Round(vPosY + vPosH/2)
MouseMove, %vPosX%, %vPosY%

vList = View,On Top,Default
MenuRCSelectItem(vList)
MouseMove, %vPosX2%, %vPosY2%
Return
#IfWinActive

;===============

MenuRCSelectItem(vList, vDelim=",", vPosX="", vPosY="", vDelay=0)
{
DetectHiddenWindows, Off
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
MouseGetPos, vPosX2, vPosY2
(vPosX = "") ? (vPosX := vPosX2)
(vPosY = "") ? (vPosY := vPosY2)

if !(vPosX = vPosX2) OR !(vPosY = vPosY2)
MouseMove, %vPosX%, %vPosY%
Click right

Loop, Parse, vList, %vDelim%
{
vTemp := A_LoopField
WinGet, hWnd, ID, ahk_class #32768
    if !hWnd
    {
    MsgBox error
    Return
    }

oAcc := Acc_Get("Object", "1", 0, "ahk_id " hWnd)
Loop, % oAcc.accChildCount
if (Acc_Role(oAcc, A_Index) = "menu item")
if (oAcc.accName(A_Index) = vTemp)
if (1, oRect := Acc_Location(oAcc, A_Index), vIndex := A_Index)
break

vPosX := Round(oRect.x + oRect.w/2)
vPosY := Round(oRect.y + oRect.h/2)
MouseMove, %vPosX%, %vPosY%
Sleep %vDelay% ;optional delay
oAcc.accDoDefaultAction(vIndex)
WinWaitNotActive, ahk_id %hWnd%, , 6
    if ErrorLevel
    {
    MsgBox error
    Return
    }
}

MouseMove, %vPosX2%, %vPosY2%
Return
}

;==================================================
```